# How to validate a textview in android?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a text-view with one background image (e.g. a signature image). When the user clicks on the text-view it retrieves a sign from the database and sets it as a background for the text-view. I want to validate the text-view (i.e. ensure that the text-view background is a signature or database sign).

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [getBackground()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html) to get the drawable that is currently set as the background.'

However, a better method would be to use `setTag("signature")` when setting the signature image, and `setTag("database")` when setting the database image, and then comparing it later using `((String)getTag()).equals(<whatever you want to check>)`